# Does sorting a vector of std::wstring actually rewrite the raw string data?

Tags: c++, string, sorting, c++11, vector

Let's sort a `vector` of 1 million of strings with:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> v;           
// fill the vector
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Does it:

1. rewrite the vector with new `wstring`s, containing a few bytes for the `wstring` structure itself + a pointer to the unmodified actual raw data, **without rewriting / moving the actual characters raw data**

or

2. rewrite the vector with new `wstring`s **and the actual characters raw data is also rewritten / moved**?

If the strings are, say, 100 character-long on average, I can imagine that 2. would be considerably slower than 1.

**Which of these 2 situations is true on C++03 ? On C++11?**

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure it is guaranteed to do the first option, I'm pretty sure it moves `std::wstring` structures which are constant in size (they do not depend on the size of the string).

The bytes representing the string are not inside its structure, there just are a pointer to a memory zone where they allocated.

Comment: Yes, the question is indeed: does it rewrite the `sizeof(std::wstring)` bytes (often = 24 or 32) for each string, but keep the same pointer / same memory zone allocated  (solution 1)? Or does it reallocate new bytes for the string data (solution 2)?

Comment: First option for sure. Not only would be faster, but more generic, because the second option would be a weird form of "deep moving things" in C++.

Answer (score 1):

`std::wstring` copy/move constructors or preferably swap method (depends on implementation) should handle this and swap internal pointers instead of data. As relevant `std::basic_string` properties weren't changed since C++03 standard version won't affect performance in this case.

Compiler and its standard library implementation however will. Also remember, that if you care about performance you should run benchmarks and use profiler.

Answer (score 1):

Neither 1. nor 2. exactly.

`std::sort` swaps elements with (`std::`)`swap`. No new elements are created (unlike your 1. suggests). Only the existing ones will be modified. However, the character data does not need to be touched (unlike your 2. suggests). Simply the size, iterator, pointer etc. data is copied from one string to the other. Although, this depends on implementation. Only guarantee is that the complexity is constant.

This did not change in C++11 as far as standard strings are concerned. However, custom types that rely on the default `std::swap` are more efficient to sort due to more efficient generic `std::swap` that benefits from move semantics.

Comment: Thanks. `Simply the size, iterator, pointer etc. data is copied from one string to the other` this is great. So is it guaranteed that the actual raw characters data is never rewritten? (is there a source about this in the c++ draft or elsewhere?)

Comment: @Basj There are no guarantees about touching the memory. In particular, an implementation that uses small string optimization would definitely copy the character data when swapping small strings. But the complexity is guaranteed to be constant, which is all I care about.

Comment: Ok that's cool then. Where would be a reference for such questions, giving details about this? I don't find any mention about what part of the data is rewritten or not on [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).

Answer (score 0):

`std::wstring` is permitted to and typically does use the small string optimization.  This means for short strings, the characters are stored *within* the `std::wstring`.  For longer strings, the `std::wstring` stores a pointer to the buffer of characters in the free store (aka the heap).

When you sort a container of `std::wstring`s, the `std::wstring`s are conceptually moved around.  The buffer of characters on the free store are passed from one `std::wstring` instance to another, and never duplicated or modified.  The "small string" cases can be modified and copied around.

This is true both in C++11 and in C++03.

Prior to C++11, there where some implementations of `std::wstring` that used copy on write smart pointers.  C++11 tightened requirements on `std::basic_string` which made such implementations illegal.  COW (copy on write) smart pointer strings rarely use SBO (I guess they could).

`std::sort` is written in terms of `std::swap`, which was specialized for `std::basic_string` or uses `std::move` to efficiently not reallocate the buffer.